# Django | Почему моё приложение не видит шаблоны?

Tags: django, django-template

хотел немного попробовать свои знания в Django (они далеки до среднего уровня). Я создал приложение **homee** (потому-что срукожопил в командной строке), если в приложении соответствует шаблон **''** , то перенаправить на **'home/'**. Всё работало, и я создал: **/templates/homee/home.html**, и в файле **views** я его попытался отрендерить. Но мне выводило ошибку.
Мой код (**homee/views.py**):

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from datetime import date, datetime

# Create your views here.
def Index(req):
    return redirect('/home')

def Home(req):
    time_now = datetime.now()
    formated_time_now = f"{time_now.hour}:{time_now.minute}:{time_now.second}"
    context = {'site_name': 'Home page', 'cur_time': formated_time_now}

    return render(req, 'homee/home.html', context)
```

А ошибка:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/home/

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\FlashStinger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\homee\home.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\FlashStinger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\homee\home.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FlashStinger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\FlashStinger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FlashStinger\Desktop\Test\myapp\homee\views.py", line 13, in Home
    return render(req, 'homee/home.html', context)
  File "C:\Users\FlashStinger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\FlashStinger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\FlashStinger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/
Exception Value: homee/home.html
```

Comment: в `settings.py` в TEMPLATES пропиши `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],`

Comment: @em0ji не работает.

Comment: ну надо как минимум смотреть файлы `urls.py` а так в ошибке указано, что `Django` не может найти  шаблоны по пути в котором  его не ищет (где происходит поиск - перечислено в сообщении об ошибке). Надо правильно настроить путь к шаблону который хотите отрендерить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребят, оказывается я просто не добавил своё приложение в настройки проекта. В файле `settings.py` в список установленных приложений требовалось добавить конфиг своего приложения.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).